# Getting random output from Crypto++

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

Can't figure out why I am getting seemingly random output from the Crypto++ RC2 decoder. The input is always the same, but the output is always different.

```
const char * cipher     ("o4hk9p+a3+XlPg3qzrsq5PGhhYsn+7oP9R4j9Yh7hp08iMnNwZQnAUrZj6DWr37A4T+lEBDMo8wFlxliuZvrZ9tOXeaTR8/lUO6fXm6NQpa5P5aQmQLAsmu+eI4gaREvZWdS0LmFxn8+zkbgN/zN23x/sYqIzcHU");
int          keylen     (64);

unsigned char keyText[] = { 0x1a, 0x1d, 0xc9, 0x1c, 0x90, 0x73, 0x25, 0xc6, 0x92, 0x71, 0xdd, 0xf0, 0xc9, 0x44, 0xbc, 0x72, 0x00 };
std::string key((char*)keyText);

std::string data;
CryptoPP::RC2Decryption rc2(reinterpret_cast<const byte *>(key.c_str()), keylen);
CryptoPP::ECB_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption rc2Ecb(rc2);
CryptoPP::StringSource
    ( cipher
    , true
    , new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder
        ( new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter
            ( rc2Ecb
            , new CryptoPP::StringSink(data)
            , CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::NO_PADDING
            )
        )
    );

std::cout << data << '\n';
```

Comment: Please make a complete example: there is nothing obviously wrong with what you are showing us, so my best guess is that the problem lies in what you are *not* showing us (i.e. where do key, keylen and cipher come from?)

Comment: They are simply constants defined immediately above, and they do decrypt properly in Java with RC2/ECB/NOPADDING.

Comment: Ah, I see you figured it out yourself. As you see, the constant can be important: it was not obvious whether keylen was the length of `key` or (as was the case) the effective key-length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters to the RC2::Decryption constructor are: (pointer to key-bytes, length of key-bytes). You are giving it a pointer to 16 bytes but using a length of 64 bytes. Crypto++ is reading uninitialized memory when reading the key, so you get random results.

If you want to indicate an effective key-length, you can use the other constructor like this:

```
CryptoPP::RC2Decryption rc2(keyText, 16, keylen);
```

Note that you should *not* use a std::string to hold your key. It is completely legal for a key to contain a 0x00-byte, and std::string is not designed to hold those.

Comment: You are wrong. std::string is designed to hold any element of type char, including '\0'. See Bjarne Stroustrup "The C++ Programming Language", 4th Ed., p1041 (p583 in 3rd Ed.).

Answer (score 0):

RC2Decryption should have been defined as:

```
CryptoPP::RC2Decryption rc2(reinterpret_cast<const byte *>(key.c_str()), key.size(), keylen);
```